# Многопоточность c++ динамическое создание мьютексов

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

Стоит задача чтения большого текстового файла порядка 16 млн. строк. В файле один блок информации состоит из 123 строк. Для данной задачи я решил использовать вектор в качестве буфера обмена, где элементы вектора так же вектора, что-то типа `vector<vector<string>>`. 
Принцип работы программы следующий: читаем файл в основном потоке main по 123 строки и пишем данный блок информации в элемент вектора `vector<vector<string>>`. Данные блоки в многопоточном режиме читаются и очищаются дочерними потоками (первоначально пробовал использовать счётчик как флаг вопрос и пример кода на стеке [проблема с многопоточным программированием на c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882219/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c)) работающими параллельно. Однако это не совсем эффективно ставить в ожидание дочерний поток, пока все потоки не отработают. Исходя их этого возникла необходимость применить другой подход (mutex, lock-free, atomic). Я остановился на mutex, однако встал вопрос как динамически создавать различное число mutex в зависимости от числа определяемых в системе параллельно работающих потоков функцией `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`
Вопрос: как создать динамически различное число mutex, записать их в хранилище (вектор, лист или наиболее подходящее) и передать ссылку в поток. Получается своего рода под каждую ячейку вектора `vector<vector<string>>` свой mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде тут ничего сложного:

```
auto p_mutexes{::std::make_unique<::std::mutex[]>(::std::thread::hardware_concurrency())};
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы, если не сложно, немного прокомментировать написанное для "особо одарённых"

Comment: @DenisDanilov Создаем массив из требуемого количества мютексов и кладем указатель на него в `unique_ptr`. Потом можно обращаться к ним как обычно, `p_mutexes[i]`

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Просто я который день пытался сам накопать эту строчку. Проще иногда спросить знающих людей, чем тратить столько времени.

Comment: А можно ещё прокомментировать, как можно его динамически проинициализировать в цикле?

Comment: @DenisDanilov Он уже проинициализирован и готов к использованию.

Comment: И последний вопрос, дайте ссылку, где это прочесть. Если не тяжело конечно. Нужны чистые знания, а не горы кода и слов.

Comment: @DenisDanilov А что подразумевается под "это"? Если нужен справочник, то можно поглядеть на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: Всё понял, спасибо за уделённое время и полезные советы.